# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException in my code iter.remove() & iter.add()

Tags: java, exception, concurrentmodification, listiterator

I have this piece of code in my class and it throws the java.util.ConcurrentModificationException on the bolded lines (indicated with** **)

```
public void solve() {
     **puzzleSolve(set.size(), sequence , set);**
}

//private helper method
protected void puzzleSolve(int k, String s, ArrayList<Character> u){


    ListIterator<Character> iter = u.listIterator();
    while(iter.hasNext())
    {
      Character c = iter.next();

      if(k==1){         //base case

            if(isAnswer(s+u.get(0)))

                System.out.println(s+u.get(0)+" is the correct sequence."+ '\n');
            return;
     }

     else{
         **iter.remove();**
         **puzzleSolve(k-1, s+c , u);** 
         iter.add(c);
         removeLastChar(s);


     }
    }

} //end of puzzleSolve method
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of your recursive calls has its own `iter`. So you're modifying the list via multiple iterators at the same time which is not allowed. You'll have to redesign...

As to redesign - you could use `for (int i = 0; i < u.size(); i++)` and remove the `i`th element from the array before making the recursive call, then insert it back with add(i, element).

I am not saying mine is a good design, but it may work...

Comment: thank you. do you possible know how i should redesign the recursive calls ? I need this to happen: for every Character c in u, i want the algoritjm to run (multiple recursion) & for each c in u, it must first remove c from u & add it to S & then at the end make all sequences of members of U